# MySQL: How to find rows with unique column values in a MyISAM table?

Tags: mysql, group-by, myisam

I need to find the rows from table t1 that have a unique (TRAN_ID,CMTE_ID) pair, where TRAN_ID and CMTE_ID are two of the columns. Then I'd like to insert these rows into the table `uniques`.

The problem is that the table `uniques` seems to end up containing duplicate pairs.

Note: table t1 was created using the InnoDb engine and then updated to use the MyISAM engine in order to speed up group by and join operations. t1 has 130 million rows.

Here's my create query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS uniques;
CREATE TABLE `uniques` (
   `CMTE_ID` varchar(9) DEFAULT '',
   `TRAN_ID` varchar(32) DEFAULT '',
   KEY `TRAN_INDEX` (`TRAN_ID`,`CMTE_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then I run the query and insert into `uniques`:

```
LOCK TABLES  uniques write, t1 write;

INSERT INTO uniques
     SELECT TRAN_ID,CMTE_ID
           FROM t1
           GROUP BY TRAN_ID,CMTE_ID
           HAVING count(*) = 1;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

At this point, I expect `uniques` to be populated with rows with unique (TRAN_ID,CMTE_ID) pairs. However, when I run

```
SELECT * FROM uniques 
    GROUP BY TRAN_ID,CMTE_ID 
    having count(*) > 1;
```

I still get a long list of rows. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to put a `unique` contraint on the pair to prevent uniques.

First guesses are operator error or the table already had data.  Discounting those, there is another possibility.  The types of the fields are:

```
`CMTE_ID` varchar(9) DEFAULT '',
`TRAN_ID` varchar(32) DEFAULT '',
```

Perhaps these are not big enough, so the data is actually being truncated when loaded into the table.  This is just an idea.  Your process seems sound.

EDIT:

Actually, I think the last is what is happening.  Your `insert` query is equivalent to:

```
INSERT INTO uniques(CMTE_ID, TRAN_ID)
     SELECT TRAN_ID,CMTE_ID
     FROM t1
     GROUP BY TRAN_ID,CMTE_ID
     HAVING count(*) = 1;
```

Note that the column orders are different, so `TRAN_ID` is being loaded into `CMTE_ID` and vice versa.  Because the types are different, the `CMTE_ID` is probably being truncated.

This is a good lesson in why you should *always* include column lists in `insert` statements.

Comment: +1 the only way he could get duplicates in the `uniques` table is that he inserted data when there was already data in the table.

Comment: Thanks for the great comment. I'm trying the fix and will report.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. Thanks for the help!